# Como recuperar o valor de um select option no Adonisjs?

Tags: html, adonisjs

```
    <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">

            <option name="tipo" value="MEMORIA" selected>MEMORIA</option>
            <option name="tipo" value="HD SSD">HD SSD</option>
            <option name="tipo"value="MONITOR">MONITOR</option>
            <option name="tipo"value="DATASHOW">DATASHOW</option>
            <option name="tipo"value="NOBREAK">NOBREAK</option>
```

Como o input text eu consigo recuperar com: hardware.tipo = request.input('tipo')

como seria em um formulario com varias opções?

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode usar o atributo name na opção para você conseguir solucionar seu problema deve inserir apenas um name e esse name deve ficar no pai ou seja no select.